# Switch to help window and select and maximize it

Tags: window

How can I open a debug window and select it and make it fill the whole frame?

I tried:

```
(let ((help-window-select t))
  (with-help-window "*Debug*"
    (dolist (item load-path) 
      (print item)))
  (delete-other-windows))
```

but this does not work; it seems to delete the help window itself and not the other windows.

**Note**:

Simply using

```
(with-help-window "*Debug*"
  (dolist (item load-path) 
    (print item)))
```

will split the frame into two windows, with the `"*Debug*"` buffer shown in the lower window. In addition the `"*Debug*"` window is not selected.

**Edit**:

I also tried:

```
(let ((buf (switch-to-buffer "*Debug*")))
  (dolist (item load-path) 
    (print item buf))
  (help-mode))
```

this creates the `"*Debug*"` buffer, but it does not select it (it stays hidden)

Comment: You could try using [`shackle`](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle). It has options to manage what happens when a popup window is opened.

Comment: @lawlist The other question seems to be about restoring the setup after quitting the help buffer. That is of course great to have. But I would like to know why the code I tried did not work. I cannot find that information in the other question.

Comment: The accepted answer in the other question (in the linked thread) does exactly what you want **and** it also sets up a key to restore the prior window configuration.  Just remove the stuff about the prior window configuration and you are done.  Alternatively, just copy the macro `help-window-full-frame` from the accepted answer and use it as-is.  The key ingredients are `delete-other-windows` (at the appropriate location in the process) and binding `help-window-select` to `t`.

Comment: Here is an example (from the accepted answer)  in the other linked-thread using `help-window-full-frame` "as-is" *without* any modifications whatsoever:  `(help-window-full-frame "*Debug*" (dolist (item load-path) (print item)))`  And if you want, just press "q" to go back to the prior window configuration.